# My mouse keeps disappearing when I click to switch tabs in chrome, why?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, mouse, lenovo-laptop, mouse-cursor

SO I recently bought a Lenovo ideapad 310 and for some reason when i'm using chrome or a word document for example, when I click to switch tabs in chrome or use the scroll bar in both word or chrome my mouse flickers and disappears and I have to click hard a few times anywhere for it to show up again. Please does anyone know what's going on or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a setting in your mouse/touchpad properties that automatically hides the cursor. This is usually meant to remove it as a distraction when you begin typing, but sometimes the software misinterprets your actions and hides it when you don't intend it to be hidden.